# Compiling OpenCV2.8 with OpenCL1.1

Tags: c++, opencv, build, opencl

I tried compiling OpenCV 2.4.13.1 with opencl 1.1 with headers from https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers

I had to change `#ifdef CL_VERSION_1_2` to `#ifdef CL_VERSION_1_1` in `opencv/cmake/checks/opencl.cpp`

also http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html suggests that it should work with OpenCL 1.1

But I still get errors like `cl_runtime_opencl.hpp:294:61: error: 'cl_device_partition_property' does not name a type` when building.

Do I have to go back to an older version to get OpenCL1.1 working? or have I missed something?

Edit: 
I don't mind an answer for OpenCV 3.0

Comment: OpenCV repo comes with OpenCL 1.2 headers included in **3rd party/include** folder. If you are using CMake GUI, make sure the `Advanced` checkbox is checked. Under OpenCL group, change the calue of `OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR` to OpenCL version 1.1 headers which you have to provide yourself.

Comment: I did that, I cloned the 1.1 headers from here (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP) and pointed OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR there

Comment: Sorry wrong link, this was the header source https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers

Comment: link `http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/` not working